# What does "(?s)" mean to htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

While reviewing the documentation of a popular framework, I stumbled upon the .htaccess code below. I pretty much understand what it does except for the `(?s)` part. What does it do?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns on the `single line mode` which makes `.` to additionally match new line characters (which it normally does not).

In this case it's redundant (and looks awkward) since the uri is a single line anyway.

References:

- [regular-expressions.info - Specifying Modes Inside The Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html)